# Claims to Windows Token Service Without Start

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016

Any ideas why there is no option to start the C2WTS from Central Administration?
I started the service on all servers in the farm and set it to automatic.  The set the service account in Security.

[image]

Edit: An image of the Min-Role setup was requested.
In case the image is not available it is 2 app servers, 1 search server, 1 wfe, & 1 wfe with distributed cache
[image]

Comment: Information that may or may not be relevant.  I did this yesterday.  When I opened the servers this morning, the service was stopped and disabled again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to MHeld's answer, I found what I needed.  This is my first MinRole farm.  I found an article on Managing a MinRole farm that showed how to start and stop services.  A simple Start-SPService worked.

[Managing a MinRole Server Farm](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt743705(v=office.16).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you installed SharePoint 2016 in a [MinRole](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt346114(v=office.16).aspx)-Deployment. MinRole automatically starts and stops service instances on each MinRole-managed server in your farm based on the server role.

Your screenshot doesn't tell us, which Role your server has. Maybe [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt667910(v=office.16).aspx) helps you to configure MinRole to your needs.

Please provide some Screenshots from **Central-Administration -> Manage Servers in Farm** of your MinRole-Deployment if you need further help.

Comment: You are correct, I will add that to the question.

Comment: If I understand your linked article correctly, perhaps I need to ask a different question. "What service application do I need to create to activate the C2WTS service?"  BTW this all started because I can't generate a Secure Store Key.

Answer (score 3):

The "Start" button is removed from "Services in Farm" in SharePoint Server 2016 MinRole environment. If you want to start services, please go to "Configuration Wizard" to select the Service Application which you want to enable.

See the screen below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers.  I try to steer clear of the ConfigWiz to prevent GUIDs in the database names.  Perhaps I will do more research to determine when it might actually be useful in MinRole.

Answer (score 2):

Adding my two cents, In 2016 with MinRole topology there is little change.

Every role has a dedicated service attach to it. If you stop that service which required for the assigned role then overnight health analyzer role will start it again( this rule is controlling the compliant section of the services).

Same thing, if the service is not part of the selected role and you start it then over nightly run health rule will stop it again to make the server compliant again.

Like if you will start the C2WTS on search minrole server it will stop next day.

[Check this technet for more info, which role has what services.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt667910(v=office.16).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Executed below commands and started and shows active on servers in the farm.

```
$service=Get-SPService -all |where {$_.TypeName -like "Claims to Windows Token Service*"}
$service.AutoProvision=$true
$service.Update()
$service.Provision()
```